# Assistance with first time Powershell Exception catching

Tags: powershell, error-handling, exception

I am not much of a programmer, and only occasionally use powershell to accomplish some of my tasks, and as such, have never done any real error handling in my powershell scripts/commands.

I am struggling to wrap my head around catching exceptions in my example code below, as it seems to be behaving the wrong way around. here is the code:

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -SearchBase 
"OU=Desktops,OU=Computers,OU=Managed,DC=domain,DC=local" -Filter * | select Name
$Table= ""
$Computers | Foreach  {
    $Name = $_.Name
    try {
        $Table += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $Name | 
        Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Product Name"} | select PSComputerName,Name,Version
    }
    catch {
        $Name + " unavailable"
    }
}
```

What seems to happen, is when a computer is off or otherwise unavailable, the Get-WmiObject  command fails, and displays an Exception message in the powershell window. I would have expected my Catch statement to see this exception, and instead output the $Name of the computer and the text " Unavailable".

When I say it happens backwards, after displaying the exception message for the unavailable computers, for those that are successful it shows the $Name + " unavailable".

Am I misundertsanding the concept behind error handling in powershell, and how can I adjust the above code to catch the erroring computers and do something different with them?

Comment: [This article written by Adam Bertram](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2016/08/18/try-catch-block-in-powershell.aspx) is a go-to source for try/catch blocks and how they work.

Comment: Thanks Bryce, will definitely have a look at that to get an understanding of try/catch. Thanks

Comment: @BryceMcDonald [This article](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-04-10-Powershell-exceptions-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/) is also quite good at explaining all things exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Get-WmiObject` throws what's known as a *non*-terminating error - in order to have execution terminate on error and have the `catch` block execute, you need to specify `-ErrorAction Stop` when calling it:

```
try {
    $Table += Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName $Name -ErrorAction Stop |Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Product Name"} | select PSComputerName,Name,Version
}
catch {
    $Name + " unavailable"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, will give this a go

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `-ErrorAction Stop` to your `Get-WMIObject` call.

Example:

```
try{
    Get-WmiObject -Class asdf -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch{
    Write-Host error!
}
```

returns

```
error!
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan. Will give this a go